# Structure for storing data from thousands of files on a mobile device

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have more than 32000 binary files that store a certain kind of spatial data. I access the data by file name. The files range in size from 0-400kb. I need to be able to access the content of these files randomly and at various time points. I don't like the idea of having 32000+ separate files of data installed on a mobile device (even though the total file size is < 100mb). I want to merge the files into a single structure that will still let me access the data I need just as quickly. I'd like suggestions as to what the best way to do this is. Any suggestions should have C/C++ libs for accessing the data and should have a liberal license that allows inclusion in commercial, closed-source applications without any issue.

The only thing I've thought of so far is storing everything in an sqlite database, though I'm not sure if this is the best method, or what considerations I need to take into account for storing blob data with quick look up times (ie, what schema I'd use).

Comment: Can you be more specific about why you "*don't like the idea of having 32000+ separate files*"? If we don't know your specific concerns, our responses might not address them properly.

Comment: It just seems like a bad idea to have that many separate files -- I never see applications actually install asset data in such a fragmented way, its usually merged into a smaller set of files. I might even run into a limit for max number of files/folder. Plus installing/extracting 32000+ files as opposed to 1 or 2? It seems like the latter would be better, especially on a mobile device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not roll your own?

Your requirements sound pretty simple and straight forward. Just bundle everything into a single binary file and add an index at the beginning telling which file starts where and how bit it is.

30 lines of C++ code max. Invest a good 10 minutes designing a good interface for it so you could replace the implementation when and if the need occurs.

That is of course if the data is read only. If you need to change it as you go, it gets hairy fast.

Comment: I didn't have any specific reason for not doing this outside of convenience -- but maybe the simplicity with this particular situation means rolling my own is the best solution.